# errors when clipping raster stacks with sf::st_crop() and raster::crop()

Tags: r, ggplot2, crop, raster

My code produces a map from a raster stack of three layers selected from a hyperspectral reflectance raster stack, plus polygon(s).

```
my_rfl <- raster::stack("./filepath/my_raster.bsq")
my_pdk <- read_sf("./data/shp/my_pdk.shp") 

my_stack <- subset(my_rfl, c(18, 30, 68))

my_map <- ggplot() +
  geom_spatial_rgb(data = my_stack, mapping = aes(x = x, 
                                                  y = y,
                                                  r = red,
                                                  g = green,
                                                  b = blue), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_sf(data = pdk, colour = "blue", fill = "NA")
my_map
```

[image: full raster with polygon overlaid]

I only want to see the area of the raster that's within the polygon, so I do:

```
my_stack <- raster::crop(my_stack, my_pdk)
```

or

```
my_stack <- st_crop(my_stack, my_pdk)
```

But `raster::crop()` seems to lose the red layer, throwing: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'red' not found`, when I try to print the map. I have also tried `raster::mask()`, same result.

`st_crop` throws `Error in UseMethod("st_crop") :  no applicable method for 'st_crop' applied to an object of class "c('RasterBrick', 'Raster', 'RasterStackBrick', 'BasicRaster')"`

Answer (score 2):

First: next time make a reproducible example so it is easier to help you; Second: always include your `library` so it is clear where the functions you use came from.
However, I think the problem is that when you `crop` the `raster::stack` it is converted to a `raster::brick`. See the code below:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(terrain)
#generate example data
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
s <- stack(r,r*0.5,r/3)
names(s) <- c("red","green","blue")
cds1 <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-150,-20))
polys <- spPolygons(cds1)
polys <- st_as_sf(polys)

 ggplot() +
  geom_spatial_rgb(data = s, mapping = aes(x = x, 
                                                  y = y,
                                                  r = red,
                                                  g = green,
                                                  b = blue), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_sf(data = polys, colour = "blue", fill = "NA")
```

[image]

```
#first crop to the extantion of the polygon
my_stack <- stack(raster::crop(s, polys))
#then mask out (i.e. assign NA) the values outside the polygon
my_stack <- stack(raster::mask(my_stack, polys))

ggplot() +
  geom_spatial_rgb(data = my_stack, mapping = aes(x = x, 
                                           y = y,
                                           r = red,
                                           g = green,
                                           b = blue), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_sf(data = polys, colour = "blue", fill = "NA")
```

the plot now looks like this
[image]
and as you can see the extent of the `raster::stack` is the same as the polygon

```
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 6, 10, 60, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent     : -160, -60, -60, 0  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names      :   red, green,  blue 
min values : 327.0, 163.5, 109.0 
max values : 507.0, 253.5, 169.0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and also the method for producing the raster and poly for my reprex - I had no idea how to do that.